# How to pass multiple variables in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that I'm trying to write to a file using multiple variables, but one of them is being ignored.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=/folder
name=bob
date=`date +%Y`

command > $dir/$name_$date.ext
```

The `$name` is being ignored. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use: `command > "${dir}/${name}_${date}.ext"`

Comment: `set -u` might be a good idea.

Comment: Your code uses the var `name_`. When you cannot change the last line into fields with `{}`, you can work around with `name_=bob_`.

Comment: That workaround is evil... Just don't.

Comment: @Karoly: It is evil indeed, I included it for showing what is happening and encouraging the normal method showed by anubhava.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you noticed that the `_` was "ignored" as well? That's a big hint.
If you use `set -u`, you'll see the following:

```
-bash: name_: unbound variable
```

The way bash parses it, the underscore is part of the variable name.

There are several ways to fix the problem.
The cleanest is the `${var}` construct which separate the variable name from its surroundings.
You can also use quotation in various ways to force the right parsing, e.g.: `"$dir/$name""_$date.ext"`

And in case your variables might contain spaces (now, or in the future) use quotation for words.

```
command >"$dir/${name}_$date.ext"
command >"${dir}/${name}_${date}.ext"
```

Both these are fine, just pick one style and stick to it.

Comment: Ah, forgot that _ can be part of a variable. Thanks!